# What tags can I use inside <article> tags

Tags: html

`<article>` is one of the new HTML5 sectioning elements. It is often confused with `<section>` and `<div>`, but I don't know what tags I can use inside it.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article). [Flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) is permitted content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<article>` tag specifies independent, self-contained content.

An article should make sense on its own and it should be possible to distribute it independently from the rest of the site.

The article element represents a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

The section element represents a generic section of a document or application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a heading. [...]

Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in a tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction, news items, and contact information.

Inside the article tag, you can use most common tags. Though as per the description given in the above mentioned links, I won't suggest using them.

Here are some of the links that might help you out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/section

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article

Answer (score 1):

http://html5doctor.com/the-article-element/
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp

You can pretty much put any valid tags inside the article tag. The article tag is really only different from a div in that it is semantic, meaning it clearly describes itself to the developer and the browser.